# How to find the same index between two dataframes and combine it to a new dataframe, Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas.dataframes `df1` and `df2`. Some of their index are equal. I want to find those index and combine the corresponding rows into a new dataframe.

```
df1 =
        A    B
Name
apple   1    5
orange  2    6
banana  3    7


df2 =
        A    B
Name
apple  -1   10
audi   -2   11
bmw     0   12
banana  2    8
vw     -3    6
```

The new dataframe that I want is: 1) find the rows with the same index; 2) calculate the average value of the corresponding rows in column 'A'.

```
df_new = 
        A_average   
Name
apple   0   
banana  2.5
```

This is because: `df1` and `df2` both have the index `apple` and `banana`. The average value of `apple` in column 'A' is `(1-1)/2=0`, and the average value of `banana` in column 'A' is `(3+2)/2=2.5`.

Do you know how to use Python3 to achieve this? Please note that, in my real application, there can be many more rows than the example I showed above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
You could concatenate the two dataframes and group by columns.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], 1).dropna().mean(axis=1, level=0)

          A    B
apple   0.0  7.5
banana  2.5  7.5
```

If it's just `A` you want, then this should suffice -

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], 1).dropna()['A'].mean(axis=1, level=0)

          A
apple   0.0
banana  2.5
```

---

**Option 2**
An alternative would be to find the intersecting indices with `index.intersection` and index with `loc` -

```
i = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

df1.loc[i, ['A']].add(df2.loc[i, ['A']]).div(2)

          A
Name       
apple   0.0
banana  2.5
```

Comment: Note that [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) may mess up the ordering of the index (I guess the operation is based on sets). Also note that the default behavior with respect to sorting has slightly changed across recent versions of pandas.